# Image overlay on hover in the e-mail

Tags: css, email, hover, overlay, html-email

I would like to fade in product description underneath its picture, using overlay effect on hover, in the e-mail. Unfortunately, Gmail doesn't support some CSS functions. When I send the e-mail, the product description displays below the picture. Is it possible to display text instead of picture when you hover your cursor over the image in the e-mail? Do you know which CSS function is not supported by the e-mail service providers?

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: #008CBA;
}

.container:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}

.text {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 385px;
  display:block;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <img src="https://ecsmedia.pl/c/wojny-i-noce-b-iext73211797.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="image">
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="text">„Wojny i Noce" to trzeci długogrający album Darii Zawiałow, którego zapowiedź stanowią dreampopowe hity „Kaonashi" oraz „Za krótki sen" nagrany z Dawidem Podsiadło. Nowy album to kolejny longplay, przygotowany w songwriterskim duecie Daria + Michał Kush. Oprócz wydania CD, Daria przygotowała dla fanów wyjątkowe LP - Picture Disc z motywem Sakury czyli kwiatu wiśni.</div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: FYI for people reading above, the OP means CSS transitions, not functions. CSS transitions aren't supported in Gmail.

Comment: Sorry g-mail is not a webkit client. so it is not supported at all, they do not support key frames animation. so I do not believe it is possible to get the desired effect in your e-mail. not even with script as this may cause a conflict with security and cause the mail to get blocked or go to the junk. So you answered your own question.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment, no support for CSS transitions in Gmail. Further to that, position is not supported in any Gmail client - https://www.caniemail.com/search/?s=position

You'll need to find an alternative method of showing your caption across the board.